# Numero aleatorio de 36 digitos en C#

Tags: c#

Quiero obtener un numero de 36 digitos aleatorios en C#, utilice el Random pero no pude hacer que el numero de digitos solo fuera 36

Saludos y gracias

Comment: la forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es usar un vector de int[36]
y ir casilla por casilla metiendo el número aleatorio del 0 al 9 PD: después de eso solo lo recorre y lo concatena

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que podrías acomularlos en una variable String si lo que quieres es un número tan largo.

```
Random random = new Random();
String numero="";
for(int i=0;i<36;i++){
    numero +=  Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 9));
 
}
```

De esta forma tendrías un número de 36 dígitos aleatorio guardado en una variable String. Si lo que quieres es hacer cálculos con el la cosa se complica.

Que yo sepa el valor máximo de `Int64` según microsof es `9.223.372.036.854.775.807`

> [Int64 de microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Int32 de microsfot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Límites de Integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)

Si intentas pasar ese número a una variable **int** básicamente te va a dar

> **System.OverflowException:** 'Valor demasiado grande o demasiado pequeño para `tipo de valor`.'